# Complete, immersed $M^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with constant curvature $K>0\Rightarrow M=$ sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

I'm trying to prove/disprove the following proposition:

> Let $M^2$ be a complete, connected, two-dimensional manifold with positive, constant curvature. If $f:M^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ an immersion such that $f(M)$ is contained in a sphere $S$, then $f(M)=S$.

One idea is to use Hilbert's theorem on the rigidity of the sphere, but in that case we would need $M$ to be compact, which I don't know is necessarily the case. Another idea is to prove $f(M)$ is an open set of $S$ which, by completeness, would mean $f(M)=S$ (since complete manifolds are not extendable), but I couldn't prove it either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A complete Riamennian surface with $K \ge \delta >0$ for some $\delta$ [is compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%27s_theorem)

Comment: If $M$ is any compact surface and $f: M\to S^2$ is an immersion then $f$ is an open and closed map, hence, is surjective.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I can see that an immersion $f:M\to\mathbb{S}^2$ must be a local diffeomorphism, therefore an open map. But why is $f$ closed?

Comment: Continuous mapping from a compact set has compact (thus closed) image @rmdmc89

Comment: @ArcticChar, I agree that $f(M)$ is compact (thus closed). But when Moishe Kohan said "$f$ closed" I thought he meant $f$ takes closed sets to closed sets, right?

Comment: @rmdmc89: Yes: Every closed subset of $M$ will be compact, so its image will be compact, hence, closed.